# Phonegap Change Project in Dreamweaver CC

Tags: dreamweaver, phonegap-build

I am using Dreamweaver CC to build my project using phonegap service, I have tested my project to build it for the 1st time, after successful build I have change the project folder name and some files too, Now dreamweaver doesn't allow me to rebuild and said "you have exceeded your allowed number of application".
Is there any way to resolve this issue, I dont wanna purchase any plan

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. If you are registered in only adobe phonegap premit you two free applications. and these are listed in your account with the name you put on your application and detail. If you want to make a new application must phonegap entering adobe, double clicking the name of the application, thus it opens a page with the application settings and there you can search and find a button to delete the old application if that's what you want. But you must pay for the right to raise more applications.